# Counting the total number of ocurrences of a set of words using grep in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have a set of words 
`happy enjoy dead cheerful`

I want to count the **total number** of appearances of these words in a text file `q.txt`

Right now I am using `grep` to count the individual words and then adding them, but it is not at all efficient for adding more words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by total no. of appearances? Do you want to output the total of each one separately or the total of all the words combine?

I would do something like this:

put the words you want to count in a separate file, words.txt, one per line. Then if you want to output each individual word with its count:

```
for i in `cat words.txt`; do
    echo -n "$i - "
    grep -c $i q.txt
done
```

If you just want the sum of all the numbers, maybe something like this:

```
for i in `cat words.txt`; do
    grep -c $i q.txt
done| awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}'
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) => http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 instead

Comment: Note that you need to pass some additional options to avoid matching words like "enjoyable" or "deadly": `grep -F -w -c`

Answer (score 3):

```
words="happy enjoy dead cheerful"
regex=$(set -- $words; IFS='|'; echo "$*")
grep -o -E -w "$regex" q.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

---

With the total:

```
while read -r count word; do
    (( t += count ))
    printf "%8d %s\n" "$count" "$name"
done < <(grep -o -E -w "$regex" q.txt | sort | uniq -c)
echo total is $t
```

Comment: Alternatively: `words=(happy enjoy dead cheerful); grep ${words[@]/#/-e } q.txt ...`

Comment: Can you edit it so that there is a final variable `$t` which holds the value of the sum of all appearances of all words ie `happy - 3`, `dead - 2` then `$t - 5`

Answer (score 0):

With single **awk** process.
 Besides, I believe, that this will go much faster on "big" files comparatively with `grep` + `sort` + `uniq`:

Sample `q.txt`:

```
I thought that the aim of life is to be happy. Till you not dead -  you enjoy of life and feeling cheerful.
Just enjoy and then dead ...
Everyone want to be happy. Am I happy?
Just remember that we'll all die. Live like dead man, striving to recreate hisself ... and not just dreaming about cheerful, 
enjoy, happy ...
```

---

```
awk -v RS='[,."?!]*[[:space:]]+' '/happy|enjoy|dead|cheerful/{ a[$0]++ }
           END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' q.txt
```

The output:

```
cheerful 2
enjoy 3
happy 4
dead 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Timing some of the answers.

I concatenated /usr/share/dict/words a bunch of times to create a large file

```
$ ll words
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jackman jackman 653M Sep 19 11:10 words
```

grep|sort|uniq

```
$ time sh -c 'grep -oEw "happy|enjoy|dead|cheerful" words | sort | uniq -c'
    729 cheerful
   1458 dead
    729 enjoy
    729 happy

real    0m2.232s
user    0m2.148s
sys 0m0.084s
```

awk

```
$ time awk -v RS='[,."?!]*[[:space:]]+' '/happy|enjoy|dead|cheerful/{ a[$0]++ } END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' words
deaden 729
deadliness 729
deader 729
deadline 729
deadbeats 729
deadens 729
cheerfuller 729
deadened 729
deadliest 729
enjoyable 729
deadlock's 729
dead's 729
deadbolts 729
cheerfulness 729
deadlier 729
deadbolt's 729
deadbeat's 729
happy 729
deadwood 729
cheerfully 729
enjoyment's 729
deadpan's 729
deadbeat 729
deadbolt 729
deadliness's 729
cheerfullest 729
enjoyments 729
deadlock 729
enjoyment 729
deadpan 729
deadpanned 729
dead 729
enjoy 729
deadest 729
deadpanning 729
deadly 729
enjoys 729
slaphappy 729
unhappy 729
deadlocks 729
deadlines 729
deadpans 729
deadening 729
enjoyed 729
deadlocked 729
deadwood's 729
cheerfulness's 729
deadline's 729
enjoying 729
deadlocking 729
cheerful 729

real    0m46.817s
user    0m46.720s
sys 0m0.228s
```

awk but simplified, since we know the structure of the file is one word per line, and avoiding regular expression matching.

```
$ time awk -v w="happy enjoy dead cheerful" '
    BEGIN {n=split(w,a); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) words[a[i]]=1} 
    $1 in words {count[$1]++} 
    END {for (word in count) print count[word], word}
' words
729 cheerful
729 enjoy
729 happy
729 dead

real    0m13.781s
user    0m13.652s
sys 0m0.164s
```

would it be faster to do straight string equality comparison since the list of "needle" words is short?

```
$ time awk '                                 
    $1 == "happy" || $1 == "enjoy" || $1 == "dead" || $1 == "cheerful" {count[$1]++} 
    END {for (word in count) print count[word], word}
' words
729 cheerful
729 enjoy
729 happy
729 dead

real    0m32.738s
user    0m32.668s
sys 0m0.156s
```

No. It seems the `in` operator is quick.

Surprisingly (to me), grepping the file multiple times is still quite fast:

```
$ time sh -c 'for i in happy enjoy dead cheerful; do echo "$(grep -cFx "$i" words) $i"; done'
729 happy
729 enjoy
729 dead
729 cheerful

real    0m2.480s
user    0m2.132s
sys 0m0.348s
```

Anyway, the `grep|sort|uniq` pipeline is speediest so far.

---

A new winner: grepping the file multiple times but with different options:

```
$ time sh -c 'for i in happy enjoy dead cheerful; do echo "$(grep -cw "$i" words) $i"; done'
729 happy
729 enjoy
1458 dead
729 cheerful

real    0m1.708s
user    0m1.348s
sys 0m0.356s
```

Comment: Note that "dead" shows up twice as often because my word file contains both `dead` and `dead's`.